# sift features for "similar" objects

Tags: image-processing, sift

I find out that [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform)  features is only good for find the same object in the scene, but it seems not suitable for "similar" objects.

maybe I doing something wrong?
maybe I must use some other descriptors?

images and SIFT\ASIFT algorithms work:

[link](http://www.ipol.im/pub/demo/my_affine_sift/archive?key=0E6EAE29E2C5D31A2898F869A8DAF83A)

same problem- no matches

[link](http://www.ipol.im/pub/demo/my_affine_sift/archive/?key=B0DC021AA9AEED012DDD02F3DCC8BB6B)

Comment: I know about haar features(drawbacks- many scales) and template matching(drawbacks- no rotate and scale invariance)

Comment: SIFT features are used quite successfully to find (perceptual) similar images. I think you need to put in some more hours to learn.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I mean,  I don't want some clusterisation of templates or CBIR system, I tryed ASIFT and SIFT look at the pictures http://www.ipol.im/pub/demo/my_affine_sift/archive?key=0E6EAE29E2C5D31A2898F869A8DAF83A  they have no matches.

Comment: Can you please add the images to your question? Then it is a bit more clear to everybody what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic SIFT algorithm using [VLfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html) gives me this as a result. Which given the small and not so unique target image, is a pretty good result I would say.

[image]

Comment: I think it found just the plane that was croped from the scene, but why it can't find other planes? maybe I need to tune some settings of descriptors?

Comment: In this case, I used a rule that stipulates that a match between points is only accepted if it has the smallest euclidean distance and if it is significantly better than the second best match. You can play with this criteria yourself, and show more matches, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

> I find out that SIFT features is only good for find the same object in the scene, but it seems not suitable for "similar" objects.

It is exactly what they are doing (and not only them, task is called "wide baseline matching") - 1)for each feature find the most similar - called "tentative" or "putative" correspondence
2)use RANSAC or other similar method to find geometric transformation between sets of correspondences.

So, if you need to find "similar", you have to use other method, like Viola-Jones  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework

Or (but it will give you a lot of false positives) you can compare big image to small and do not use step 2.